# Как избавиться от повторов в цикле for в Python?

Tags: python, for, комбинаторика

У меня стоит задача пробежаться по файлам из папок в директории `speakers` и сравнить между собой все сочетания файлов внутри каждой субдиректории.

Однако когда запускаю цикл, на выходе - каждое сочетание дублируется (на рисунке пару дублей внутри субдиректории `spk1` для примера подчеркнул красным, но сочетания файлов дублируются и во всех прочих). На изображении (слева) также можно увидеть структуру папок и файлов внутри них (в каждой субдиректории - по 4 файла).

[image: Структура папок и дубли при переборе]

Каким образом можно получить при переборе все возможные сочетания файлов каждой субдиректории, но только единожды, а не как сейчас - дважды (по 12 сочетаний вместо 6-ти)?

Код:

```
import os
from itertools import combinations

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/content/drive/MyDrive/speakers'):
    for elem in files:
        res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей: [(файл 1, файл 2), (файл 1, файл 3)...(файл 3, файл 4)]
    for tuples in res:         # идем по каждому картежу в списке
        print(f'{tuples[0]}', f'{tuples[1]}')
```

Comment: На показанных вами данных воспроизвести проблему не получается, повторов нет https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8fKV.png

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас нет одинаковых имён файлов в разных папках?

Comment: Имена не повторяются, но благодарю: видимо, была накладка в колабе. Поскольку попробовал снова, и все отлично отработало

Comment: Ну и цикл `for elem in files:` здесь абсолютно лишний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, проблема находится "под капотом" Google Colab, поскольку повторная инициация того же кода спустя некоторые время дала верный результат